# how to make a watercolour brush using flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, paint, flutter-layout

I have researched a bit and got the javascript code to implement a waterbrush: https://codepen.io/kangax/pen/HFpun

but when I am implementing this, I am using 2 images as a stack and while dragging on top of the image above the previous one is removed. However, I do not want this and want 1 image to be drawn on top of the canvas. Any leads will be appreciated.

The code that I have written is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class DemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Scratch Card',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Scratch Card'),
        ),
        body: Material(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              ScratchCard(
                cover: Stack(
                  fit: StackFit.expand,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FittedBox(
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/bird.jpg',
                        repeat: ImageRepeat.repeat,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                reveal: DecoratedBox(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
                  child: Center(
                    child:
                        FittedBox(child: Image.asset('assets/flower.jpg')),
                  ),
                ),
                strokeWidth: 15.0,
                finishPercent: 50,
                onComplete: () => print('The card is now clear!'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScratchCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScratchCard({
    Key key,
    this.cover,
    this.reveal,
    this.strokeWidth = 25.0,
    this.finishPercent,
    this.onComplete,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget cover;
  final Widget reveal;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final int finishPercent;
  final VoidCallback onComplete;

  @override
  _ScratchCardState createState() => _ScratchCardState();
}

class _ScratchCardState extends State<ScratchCard> {
  _ScratchData _data = _ScratchData();

  Offset _lastPoint = null;

  Offset _globalToLocal(Offset global) {
    return (context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).globalToLocal(global);
  }

  double _distanceBetween(Offset point1, Offset point2) {
    return math.sqrt(math.pow(point2.dx - point1.dx, 2) +
        math.pow(point2.dy - point1.dy, 2));
  }

  double _angleBetween(Offset point1, Offset point2) {
    return math.atan2(point2.dx - point1.dx, point2.dy - point1.dy);
  }

  void _onPanDown(DragDownDetails details) {
    _lastPoint = _globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
  }

  void _onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    final currentPoint = _globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    final distance = _distanceBetween(_lastPoint, currentPoint);
    final angle = _angleBetween(_lastPoint, currentPoint);
    for (double i = 0.0; i < distance; i++) {
      _data.addPoint(Offset(
        _lastPoint.dx + (math.sin(angle) * i) - 25,
        _lastPoint.dy + (math.cos(angle) * i) - 25,
      ));
    }
    _lastPoint = currentPoint;
  }

  void _onPanEnd(TapUpDetails details) {
    final areaRect = context.size.width * context.size.height;
    double touchArea = math.pi * widget.strokeWidth * widget.strokeWidth;
    double areaRevealed =
        _data._points.fold(0.0, (double prev, Offset point) => touchArea);
    print('areaRect $areaRect $areaRevealed');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onPanDown: _onPanDown,
      onPanUpdate: _onPanUpdate,
      onTapUp: _onPanEnd,
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          widget.reveal,
          _ScratchCardLayout(
            strokeWidth: widget.strokeWidth,
            data: _data,
            child: widget.cover,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _ScratchCardLayout extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  _ScratchCardLayout({
    Key key,
    this.strokeWidth = 25.0,
    @required this.data,
    @required this.child,
  }) : super(
          key: key,
          child: child,
        );

  final Widget child;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final _ScratchData data;

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return _ScratchCardRender(
      strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
      data: data,
    );
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
      BuildContext context, _ScratchCardRender renderObject) {
    renderObject
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..data = data;
  }
}

class _ScratchCardRender extends RenderProxyBox {
  _ScratchCardRender({
    RenderBox child,
    double strokeWidth,
    _ScratchData data,
  })  : assert(data != null),
        _strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
        _data = data,
        super(child);

  double _strokeWidth;
  _ScratchData _data;

  set strokeWidth(double strokeWidth) {
    assert(strokeWidth != null);
    if (_strokeWidth == strokeWidth) {
      return;
    }
    _strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
    markNeedsPaint();
  }

  set data(_ScratchData data) {
    assert(data != null);
    if (_data == data) {
      return;
    }
    if (attached) {
      _data.removeListener(markNeedsPaint);
      data.addListener(markNeedsPaint);
    }
    _data = data;
    markNeedsPaint();
  }

  @override
  void attach(PipelineOwner owner) {
    super.attach(owner);
    _data.addListener(markNeedsPaint);
  }

  @override
  void detach() {
    _data.removeListener(markNeedsPaint);
    super.detach();
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    if (child != null) {
      context.canvas.saveLayer(offset & size, Paint());
      context.paintChild(child, offset);
      Paint clear = Paint()..blendMode = BlendMode.clear;
      _data._points.forEach((point) =>
          context.canvas.drawCircle(offset + point, _strokeWidth, clear));
      context.canvas.restore();
    }
  }

  @override
  bool get alwaysNeedsCompositing => child != null;
}

class _ScratchData extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Offset> _points = [];

  void addPoint(Offset offset) {
    _points.add(offset);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution to this problem. Thanks to Mr. Andres Colubri. I copied the entire package (one shown below) in a sepearte dart file and called that using the implementation as shown in the readme file by Mr. Andres Colubri.

Package:

```
    library p5;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/semantics.dart';
import "dart:math";
import "dart:ui";
import "dart:typed_data";

class PWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  PPainter painter;

  PWidget(PPainter p) {
    painter = p;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//    print("BUILDING WIDGET...");

//    print(painter);
    return new Container(
      width: painter.fillParent ? null : painter.width.toDouble(),
      height: painter.fillParent ? null : painter.height.toDouble(),
      constraints: painter.fillParent ? BoxConstraints.expand() : null, //new
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      child: new ClipRect(
          child: new CustomPaint(
            painter: painter,
            child: new GestureDetector(
              // The gesture detector needs to be declared here so it can
              // access the context from the CustomPaint, which allows to
              // transforms global positions into local positions relative
              // to the widget.
              onTapDown: (details) {
                painter.onTapDown(context, details);
              },
              onPanStart: (details) {
                painter.onDragStart(context, details);
              },
              onPanUpdate: (details) {
                painter.onDragUpdate(context, details);
              },
              onTapUp: (details) {
                painter.onTapUp(context, details);
              },
//              onTapCancel: (details) {
//
//              },
//              onPanCancel: (details) {
//
//              },
              onPanEnd: (details) {
                painter.onDragEnd(context, details);
              },
            ),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Animation tutorial
// https://flutter.io/tutorials/animation/
// and code:
// https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/website/master/_includes/code/animation/animate1/main.dart
// https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/website/master/_includes/code/animation/animate3/main.dart
class PAnimator extends AnimationController {
  PAnimator(TickerProvider v) :
        super.unbounded(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), vsync: v) {
    addStatusListener((status) {
      // Loop animation by reversing/forward when status changes.
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        reverse();
      } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
        forward();
      }
    });
  }

  void run() {
    forward();
  }
}

class PConstants {
  static int OPEN  = 0;
  static int CLOSE = 1;

  static int LINES   = 1;
  static int POINTS  = 2;
  static int POLYGON = 3;

  static final int SQUARE   = 1 << 0; // called 'butt' in the svg spec
  static final int ROUND    = 1 << 1;
  static final int PROJECT  = 1 << 2;  // called 'square' in the svg spec

  static final int MITER    = 1 << 3;
  static final int BEVEL    = 1 << 5;
}

class PPainter extends ChangeNotifier implements CustomPainter {
  bool fillParent = false;
  int width = 100;
  int height = 100;
  Canvas paintCanvas;
  Size paintSize;
  Rect canvasRect;

  int frameCount = 0;

  double mouseX = 0.0;
  double mouseY = 0.0;
  double pmouseX = 0.0;
  double pmouseY = 0.0;

  Paint backPaint = Paint();
  Paint fillPaint = Paint();
  Paint strokePaint = Paint();
  bool useFill = true;
  bool useStroke = true;

  var vertices = List<Offset>();
  Path path = new Path();
  var shapeMode = PConstants.POLYGON;

  PPainter() {
    init();
    setup();
    redraw();
  }

  bool hitTest(Offset position) => null;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    paintCanvas = canvas;
    paintSize = size;
    canvasRect = Offset.zero & paintSize;
    draw();
  }

  @override
  SemanticsBuilderCallback get semanticsBuilder {
    return (Size size) {
      // Annotate a the entire P5 widget with the label "P5 Sketch".
      // When text to speech feature is enabled on the device, a user will be
      // able to locate the sun on this picture by touch.
      var rect = Offset.zero & size;
      rect = const Alignment(0.0, 0.0).inscribe(size, rect);
      return [
        new CustomPainterSemantics(
          rect: rect,
          properties: new SemanticsProperties(
            label: 'P5 Sketch',
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          ),
        ),
      ];
    };
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuildSemantics(PPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }

  void init() {
    backPaint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    backPaint.color = Colors.white;

    fillPaint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    fillPaint.color = Colors.white;

    strokePaint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    strokePaint.color = Colors.black;
    strokePaint.strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt;
    strokePaint.strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.bevel;
  }

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Touch events

  void updatePointer(Offset offset) {
    pmouseX = mouseX;
    mouseX = offset.dx;

    pmouseY = mouseY;
    mouseY = offset.dy;
  }

  void onTapDown(BuildContext context, TapDownDetails details) {
//    print("onTapDown");
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
    final Offset offset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    updatePointer(offset);
    mousePressed();
    redraw();
  }

  void onTapUp(BuildContext context, TapUpDetails details) {
//    print("onTapUp");
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
    final Offset offset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    updatePointer(offset);
    mouseReleased();
    redraw();
  }

  void onDragStart(BuildContext context, DragStartDetails details) {
//    print("onDragStart");
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
    final Offset offset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    updatePointer(offset);
    mousePressed();
    redraw();
  }

  void onDragUpdate(BuildContext context, DragUpdateDetails details) {
//    print("onDragUpdate");
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
    final Offset offset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    updatePointer(offset);
    mouseDragged();
    redraw();
  }

  void onDragEnd(BuildContext context, DragEndDetails details) {
//    print("onDragEnd");
    mouseReleased();
    redraw();
  }

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Processing API

  void fullScreen() {
    fillParent = true;
  }

  void size(int w, int h) {
    width = w;
    height = h;
  }

  void setup() {
  }

  void draw() {
  }

  void redraw() {
    frameCount++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Color color(num r, num g, num b, [num a=255]) {
    return Color.fromRGBO(r, g, b, a/255);
  }

  void background(Color color) {
    backPaint.color = color;
    paintCanvas.drawRect(canvasRect, backPaint);
  }

  void stroke(Color color) {
    strokePaint.color = color;
    useStroke = true;
  }

  void strokeWeight(num weight) {
    strokePaint.strokeWidth = weight.toDouble();
  }

  void strokeCap(int cap) {
    if (cap == PConstants.SQUARE) {
      strokePaint.strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt;
    }
    if (cap == PConstants.ROUND) {
      strokePaint.strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
    }
    if (cap == PConstants.PROJECT) {
      strokePaint.strokeCap = StrokeCap.square;
    }
  }

  void strokeJoin(StrokeJoin join) {
    if (join == PConstants.BEVEL) {
      strokePaint.strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.bevel;
    }
    if (join == PConstants.MITER) {
      strokePaint.strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.miter;
    }
    if (join == PConstants.ROUND) {
      strokePaint.strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round;
    }
  }

  void noStroke() {
    useStroke = false;
  }

  void fill(Color color) {
    fillPaint.color = color;
    useFill = true;
  }

  void noFill() {
    useFill = false;
  }

  void ellipse(num x, num y, num w, num h) {
    final rect = new Offset(x - w/2, y - h/2) & new Size(w, h);
    if (useFill) {
      paintCanvas.drawOval(rect, fillPaint);
    }
    if (useStroke) {
      paintCanvas.drawOval(rect, strokePaint);
    }
  }

  void line(num x1, num y1, num x2, num y2) {
    if (useStroke) {
      paintCanvas.drawLine(new Offset(x1, y1), new Offset(x2, y2), strokePaint);
    }
  }

  void point(num x, num y) {
    if (useStroke) {
      var points = [new Offset(x, y)];
      paintCanvas.drawPoints(PointMode.points, points, strokePaint);
    }
  }

  void quad(num x1, num y1, num x2, num y2, num x3, num y3, num x4, num y4) {
    beginShape();
    vertex(x1, y1);
    vertex(x2, y2);
    vertex(x3, y3);
    vertex(x4, y4);
    endShape(PConstants.CLOSE);
  }

  void rect(num x, num y, num w, num h) {
    final rect = new Offset(x.toDouble(), y.toDouble()) & new Size(w.toDouble(), h.toDouble());
    if (useFill) {
      paintCanvas.drawRect(rect, fillPaint);
    }
    if (useStroke) {
      paintCanvas.drawRect(rect, strokePaint);
    }
  }

  void triangle(num x1, num y1, num x2, num y2, num x3, num y3) {
    beginShape();
    vertex(x1, y1);
    vertex(x2, y2);
    vertex(x3, y3);
    endShape();
  }

  void beginShape([int mode = 3]) {
    shapeMode = mode;
    vertices.clear();
  }

  void vertex(num x, num y) {
    vertices.add(Offset(x.toDouble(), y.toDouble()));
  }

  void endShape([int mode = 0]) {
    if (0 < vertices.length) {
      if (shapeMode == PConstants.POINTS || shapeMode == PConstants.LINES) {
        var vlist = List<double>();
        for (var v in vertices) { vlist.add(v.dx); vlist.add(v.dy); }
        var raw = Float32List.fromList(vlist);
        if (shapeMode == PConstants.POINTS) {
          paintCanvas.drawRawPoints(PointMode.points, raw, strokePaint);
        } else {
          paintCanvas.drawRawPoints(PointMode.lines, raw, strokePaint);
        }
      } else {
        path.reset();
        path.addPolygon(vertices, mode == PConstants.CLOSE);
        if (useFill) {
          paintCanvas.drawPath(path, fillPaint);
        }
        if (useStroke) {
          paintCanvas.drawPath(path, strokePaint);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void translate(num tx, num ty) {
    paintCanvas.translate(tx.toDouble(), ty.toDouble());
  }

  void rotate(num angle) {
    paintCanvas.rotate(angle.toDouble());
  }

  void scale(num sx, num sy) {
    paintCanvas.scale(sx.toDouble(), sy.toDouble());
  }

  void push() {
    paintCanvas.save();
  }

  num radians(num angle) {
    return (angle / 180) * pi;
  }

  num degrees(num angle) {
    return (angle / pi) * 180;
  }

  void pop() {
    paintCanvas.restore();
  }

  void mousePressed() { }

  void mouseDragged() { }

  void mouseReleased() { }
}

class PVector {
  double x = 0.0;
  double y = 0.0;
  double z = 0.0;

  PVector(double x, double y, [double z = 0.0]) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
}
```

and the implementation is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import "./package5.dart";


class WaterBrushPaint extends StatefulWidget {
  WaterBrushPaint({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  WaterBrushPaintState createState() {
    return new WaterBrushPaintState();
  }
}

class WaterBrushPaintState extends State<WaterBrushPaint> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  MySketch sketch;
  PAnimator animator;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    sketch = new MySketch();
    // Need an animator to call the draw() method in the sketch continuously,
    // otherwise it will be called only when touch events are detected.
    animator = new PAnimator(this);
    animator.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        sketch.redraw();
      });
    });
    animator.run();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("P5 Draw!")),
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(200, 200, 200, 1.0),
      body: new Center(
        child:new PWidget(sketch),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MySketch extends PPainter {

  var strokes = new List<List<PVector>>();

  void setup() {
    fullScreen();
  }

  void draw() {
    background(color(255, 255, 255));

    noFill();
    strokeWeight(10);
    stroke(color(10, 40, 200, 60));
    for (var stroke in strokes) {
      beginShape();
      for (var p in stroke) {
        vertex(p.x, p.y);
      }
      endShape();
    }
  }

  void mousePressed() {
    strokes.add([new PVector(mouseX, mouseY)]);
  }

  void mouseDragged() {
    var stroke = strokes.last;
    stroke.add(new PVector(mouseX, mouseY));
  }
}
```

Comment: You might note that the package that he is using is not compatible with dart versions greater than 2.0. However, if one does copy the entire package as a seperate file and calls it the way he is implementing you may get a solution.